# how to use custom Blender texture as the colors for a ColorRamp node? or equivalent

Tags: texturing, shaders, color

I have some code that generates a blender texture for me:

[image: texture]

and can now access it through:

```
bpy.data.textures[0]
```

I would like to use this color ramp as a shader node whereby the color ramp node has the same levels/colors as my texture.

Is there a simple way to do this?

[image]

Comment: The texture system has pretty much been abandoned by the devs for a few years now. It doesn't (AFAIK) interact with the shader nodes.

Comment: dang. I'm using template_color_ramp in some add-on I am creating, and it requires the ramp to be stored as a texture to use the UI function. I eventually want to create a shader node tree with a matching coloramp node. Thought there would be an elegant way to reuse the texture.

Comment: Ok so bear with me. You can create a material and make it not appear in the material list if its name begins with `.`. Then, inside this material node tree, create a color ramp node. Then you can reference this color ramp node in the template inside your addon. Does that make sense ? [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShaderNodeValToRGB.html#bpy.types.ShaderNodeValToRGB.color_ramp) oh and you can directly edit the material color ramp in your example too

Comment: I think I understand and just tested something in my add-on. It 
looks like to do this  I would have to create this dummy material before I even create the UI element, which doesn't really fit with my workflow. I need to create the material after the fact. And it seems like the color_ramp attributes are read only so I cant create a material and then reset the color_ramp attribute to the one that's in my add-on element. Maybe I'm just confusing myself..

Comment: My workaround is to have a unique ID for the texture name, and upon material creation, also have this unique ID as the name. And in my custom node in my add-on, my update function for this particular node will check for this matching material and sync the colorramps dynamically

Comment: Another workaround would be to use drivers, with code it can be automated. You do have to use one driver per channel (r,g and b), which makes it 3 drivers per color stop on your texture color ramp (or 4 if you use alpha), which are linked to the stops of your color ramp in your material

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this, might be more reliable.. but my code essentially does the same thing in principle

Comment: @Gorgious having just properly implemented handlers for the first time for another purpose in my addon, I believe it would be cleaner and more reliable. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

### Nodes

If you have a regular image texture, you can recreate the ramp node with other nodes.

So we have an image with a gradient along it's length and we need to remap it's length, so X coordinate, to the intensity of some other image. It's possible to do that with nodes:

[image]

I needed to reverse direction with the invert node.

### Color Ramp node with Python

If the color gradient is generated by script, why not output the colors to the Color Ramp node instead of an image?
`bpy.data.materials["Material"].node_tree.nodes["ColorRamp"].color_ramp.elements[0].color` That's the first color of my test Color Ramp node that I have in "Material". Apparently it's easy to add new elements to the ramp as well: `bpy.data.materials["Material"].node_tree.nodes["ColorRamp"].color_ramp.elements.new(0.5)`

Use autocomplete function(<kbd>Tab</kbd>) in the Python console to easily find how things work in the Python API:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, while helpful, this doesn't really answer my question or help me. I am trying to find the best way to "sync" an existing internal blender texture color ramp to a shader color ramp node. Your solution would work if I could replace the image texture In your node setup with something representing the blender texture.

Comment: I understood that you generate the ramp with some code. Can you share the code?